# Is "iterate over" being used correctly in "we briefly iterate over related work"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

Is this a correct use of the phrase "iterate over'?

> In Section Three, we briefly iterate over related work.

Answer (score 3):

In this context it is correct.

It means we carry out the task across the entirety of the problem space.

Comment: my posting was edited. could you change your answer accordingly, please? (this is strange to new visitors..)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with both Rory Alsop's and Blessed Geek's answers.

The primary meaning of *iterate* (and *reiterate*) is "To say, mention, or assert again or repeatedly; to repeat." (OED). It had a former meaning "To do (something) over again; to perform (an action) a second time, or reproduce (an effect); to repeat; to renew.", which the OED marks as "now rare".

It is certainly the case that among software people, it has acquired a more general meaning of repeating a process exactly until some condition is met, or repeating a process on each member of some set of data; but I believe that this meaning is jargon, and will not necessarily be understood by people who are not familiar with software.

While I more or less understand what you mean, I find the word inappropriate, because to me it says that you are going to methodically do exactly the same thing to each bit of the work.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate is to repetitively perform a task. If the task is transitive (i.e. has a target) over a range of targets, then we would need to say, **iterate** a task **over** that range of targets. i.e., to repetitively perform that task **over** a range of targets.

> [it·er·ate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iterate)
>   tr.v. it·er·at·ed, it·er·at·ing, it·er·ates
>   To say or perform again; repeat. See Synonyms at repeat.
>   [*Latin iterre, itert-, from iterum, **again**; see i- in Indo-European roots.*]

In algorithms and Mathematics, we would say **iterate** a task **over** a set.
Where the **set** could be a collection of discrete items, or a continuous space.

For example, to *iterate an evaluation task over a collection of one hundred stocks, at 1 minute intervals*, would be to repetitively monitor the value of each of the stocks every minute.

Sometimes iterate is used in [malapropism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) in place of *reiterate*. Reiterate is to repeat one or more time.

The difference between *iterate* and *reiterate*, is that *reiterate* can mean either

- repeat one more time or
- repetitively

Whereas, *iterate* only means

- repetitively

Both *iterate* and *reiterate* would use the preposition *over*, when applied to a collection of targets. However, the preposition is often dropped when applied to an aggregation:

> I wish to reiterate the need of contributing from each of you.
>   She had reiterated the weakness of the team.

vs

> We hope to reiterate over every student's need to contribute.
>   We need to reiterate over all the weaknesses of the team.

Reiterate normally imbues importance to the collection being *reiterated over* - where the collection is of such importance that we need to go over it one more time or repeatedly to make it sink in.

However, iterating over a collection (or set) would grammatically imbue more of a chore than importance to the collection/set.

Next time, when you hear or notice someone use the word *iterate*, kindly inquire that person if *reiterate* would be more appropriate. I suspect in the sentence which you supplied, the speaker/writer had actually meant *reiterate*.